# Applet not displaying drawString in JCreator Applet viewer

Tags: java, applet, jcreator

My applet code compiles fine, however, I receive the "Applet Started" message every time. Please do not dissuade me from using AWT or Applets. I am simply trying to complete my assignment. Currently, my code is:

main method

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Lab33ast
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Lab33ast");
        frame.add(new GfxApp());
        frame.setSize(100, 750);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()  {public void
        windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}});
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Continued, I have a paint method in a separate file. GfxApp

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GfxApp extends Panel
{

    private int td = 200;       //Time Delay on graphics

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
        g.drawString("Lab 33A 80/100 POINT VERSUIN", 300, 50);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("DRAWING A LINKED LIST AS A STACK", 50, 215);
        g.drawString("DRAWING A LINKED LIST AS A QUEUE", 50, 415);
        drawStack(g);
        drawQueue(g);

    }


    public void drawStack(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }


    public void drawQueue(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }
}
```

Next I have a file called GfxNode that our teacher told us to add without further instruction.

```
    import java.awt.*;


    public class GfxNode
    {
        private int x;                  // x coordinate of node
        private int y;                  // y coordinate of node
        private final int width;        // width of the gfx node
        private final int height;       // heigth of the gfx node
        private final int time;         // delay time between displays


    // GfxNode constructor instantiates an object and
    // stores its Top-Left coordinate (tlx,tly) information, as
    // well as the length and width of the node object.  A node object
    // with two fields is drawn at the specified coordinate.
        public GfxNode(Graphics g, int tlx, int tly, char ltr, int clr, int dt) 
        {
            x = tlx;
            y = tly;
            width = 30;
            height = 15;
            time = dt;
            drawNode(g,clr);
            drawPointer(g,ltr,1,clr);
        }


    // Method drawNode is a private helper method to draw linked list nodes.
    // This method draws a node with two fields at a location of the
    // Top-Left coordinate information in the current object.
    private void drawNode(Graphics g, int clr)
    {
        g.setColor(getColor(clr));
        g.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
        g.drawLine(x+height,y,x+height,y+height);
        delay(time);
    }


    // Method getColor a private helper method to make it easier to use colors
    // in a graphics program.   
    private Color getColor(int clr)
    {
        Color temp = Color.white;
        switch (clr)
        {
            case 0:  temp = Color.black;    break;
            case 1:  temp = Color.red;      break;
            case 2:  temp = Color.green;    break;
            case 3:  temp = Color.blue;     break;
            case 4:  temp = Color.orange;   break;
            case 5:  temp = Color.cyan;     break;
            case 6:  temp = Color.magenta;  break;
            case 7:  temp = Color.yellow;   break;
            case 8:  temp = Color.pink;     break;
            case 9:  temp = Color.white;    break;
        }
        return temp;
    }


    // Method getX returns the top-left X-coordinate of a linked list node.
    public int getx()
    { 
        return x; 
    }


// Method getY returns the top-left Y-coordinate of a linked list node.
public int gety()
{
    return y;
}


// Method drawPointer draws a vertical pointer down to an existing node.
// The first pointer to a node uses OffSet value 1 and the second
// pointer to the same node uses OffSet value 2.  The result is that
// the second pointer is moved farther to the right.
public void drawPointer(Graphics g, char ltr, int offSet, int clr) 
{
    if (offSet == 1)
        offSet = 8;
    else
        offSet = 18;
    int x1 = x + offSet;
    int y1 = y - 20;
    int x2 = x1;
    int y2 = y - 2;
    g.setColor(getColor(clr));
    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    g.drawLine(x2,y2,x2-3,y2-3);
    g.drawLine(x2,y2,x2+3,y2-3);
    drawLetter(g,ltr,x+offSet-4,y-32);
    delay(time);
}


// Method enterData draws a letter in the Data field of the GfxNode.
public void enterData(Graphics g, char ltr, int clr) 
{
    g.setColor(getColor(clr));
    drawLetter(g,ltr,x+3,y+3);  
    delay(time);
}


// Method drawLink draws a link from the current sourceNode to the
// endNode in the specified color (clr).    
public void drawLink(Graphics g, GfxNode endNode, int clr) 
{
    int x1,x2;
    int y1 = this.gety()  + height/2;
    int y2 = endNode.gety() + height/2;
    g.setColor(getColor(clr));
    if (this.getx() < endNode.getx())
    {
        x1 = this.getx() + 22;
        x2 = endNode.getx() - 2;
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        g.drawLine(x2,y2,x2-3,y2-3);
        g.drawLine(x2,y2,x2-3,y2+3);
    }
    else
    {
        x1 = endNode.getx() + 8;
        x2 = this.getx() + width + 2;
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x1-3,y1-3);
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x1-3,y1+3);
    }
    delay(time);
}


// Method drawNull draws a diagonal g.drawLine in the Next
// field of a list node, to indicate a NULL value.
public void drawNull(Graphics g, int clr)
{
    g.setColor(getColor(clr));
    g.drawLine(x+height+1,y+1,x+width-1,y+height-1);
    delay(time);
}


//  Method drawLetter upper-case Letter characters.  The characters
//  are drawn in a 9x9 pixel box.
//  The (x,y) parameters indicate the coordinate of the top-left corner
//  of the box.  Only capital letters and numbers are drawn.
public void drawLetter(Graphics g, char ltr, int x, int y) 
{
    switch (ltr)
    {
        case 'A' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+8,y+4);
            break;
        case 'B' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+5,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+5,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+5,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+5,y,x+8,y+2);
            g.drawLine(x+5,y+8,x+8,y+6);
            g.drawLine(x+5,y+4,x+8,y+2);
            g.drawLine(x+5,y+4,x+8,y+6);
            break;
        case 'C' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            break;
        case 'D' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+4,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+4,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+4,y,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+4,y+8,x+8,y+4);
            break;
        case 'E' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+6,y+4);
            break;
        case 'F' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+6,y+4);
            break;
        case 'G' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+6,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+8,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+4,x+4,y+4);
            break;
        case 'H' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+8,y+4);
            break;
        case 'I' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+4,y,x+4,y+8);
            break;
        case 'J' :
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x,y+4);
            break;
        case 'K' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+1,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+8,x+1,y+4);
            break;
        case 'L' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            break;
        case 'M' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+5,y+5);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+1,x+4,y+4+1);
            break;
        case 'N' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+9-1,y+8);
            break;
        case 'O' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            break;
        case 'P' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+4);
            break;
        case 'Q' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+3,y+5,x+8,y+10);
            break;
        case 'R' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+9,y+8);
            break;
        case 'S' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+4,x+8,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+4,x+8,y+8);
            break;
        case 'T' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x+4,y,x+4,y+8);
            break;
        case 'U' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            break;
        case 'V' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+4,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+4,y+8);
            break;
        case 'W' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+8,y+9-1);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+4,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y+8,x+4,y+4);
            break;
        case 'x' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+9,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y);
            break;
        case 'y' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+5-1,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x+4,y+4);
            g.drawLine(x+4,y+4,x+4,y+8);
            break;
        case 'Z' :
            g.drawLine(x,y,x+8,y);
            g.drawLine(x,y+8,x+8,y+8);
            g.drawLine(x+8,y,x,y+8);
            break;
        default :
            g.fillRect(x,y,8,8);
    }

}


    // Method delay allows viewing the sequence in which the linked lists are drawn/
    private void delay(double n)
    {
        for (double k = 1; k < n; k+=0.00001);
    }


}
```

I have no idea what the above code is about or its relation to my objective. Feel free to explain it to me.

I have created another class called GfxApplet and pointed to .htm code to it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class GfxApplet extends Applet
{

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        GfxApp app = new GfxApp();
        add(app);
    }

}
```

My html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="000000">
        <center>
            <applet
                code    = "Lab33ast.class"
                width   = "500"
                height  = "300"
                >
            </applet>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone can give specific and detailed solutions, I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `Applet` in your code (nothing extends from `Applet`).

Generally speaking you should start with a different container class, maybe `Panel` (since you're living in the dark ages with AWT), put all your logic into this class.

Then, when you need it, create an instance of `Frame` or make a class which extends from `Applet` and add an instance of your panel to it.

<strike>Unless you have a major driving cause to, I'd avoid using AWT directly in this way and would use Swing, Swing superseded AWT 16+ years ago, so you're likely to get better community support.  See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details</strike>

Since applets are been actively blocked by most browsers now days, I'd also question their use here

Missed the *"Please do not dissuade me from using AWT or Applets"* disclaimer

> I see the logic in extending an applet. I just have no idea where to where to put that "extends Applet" part. As I change what is extended from GfxApp, I receive numerous errors in my main method, most commonly at "gfx.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()". My IDE says that it cannot find symbol

Move your core logic to a `Panel` based class

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Panel;

public class GfxApp extends Panel {

    private int td = 200;       //Time Delay on graphics

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
        g.drawString("Lab 33A 80/100 POINT VERSUIN", 300, 50);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("DRAWING A LINKED LIST AS A STACK", 50, 215);
        g.drawString("DRAWING A LINKED LIST AS A QUEUE", 50, 415);
        drawStack(g);
        drawQueue(g);

    }

    public void drawStack(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }

    public void drawQueue(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }
}
```

Create a class which `extends` from `Applet`, add an instance of `GfxApplet` to it...

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class GfxApplet extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        GfxApp app = new GfxApp();
        add(app);
    }

}
```

Change your applet html code to point to it...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="000000">
        <center>
            <applet
                code    = "GfxApplet.class"
                width   = "500"
                height  = "300"
                >
            </applet>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you need it, you can add `GfxApp` to an instance of `Frame` when you need to...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame("Lab33ast");
    frame.add(new GfxApp());
    frame.setSize(100, 750);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void
                windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the basic of good management of your UI code

Comment: In fairness to OP the question implies it is a homework assignment, although I agree with your points in general.

Comment: @paisanco Yeah missed the basic disclaimer.  Maybe I should take it up with the instructor who seems to have lost any connection to reality

Comment: I see the logic in extending an applet. I just have no idea where to where to put that "extends Applet" part. As I change what is extended from GfxApp, I receive numerous errors in my main method, most commonly at  "gfx.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()". My IDE says that it cannot find symbol.

Comment: `Applet` isn't  a "window", it has not concept of been closed.  The applet is constructed and managed by the browser/applet plugin/applet container.  My point been, you don't need `Lab33ast`, the `code` attribute of the `applet` tag should point to your `GfxApp`

Comment: Please excuse me if I seem obnoxiously ignorant. I've not learned much with my instructor. I copy pasted the main method you provided into `33ast`. Do I add the `GfxApplet` class in the same file as `GfxApp`? Or create a different file for it? I have tried both and have received the `Cannot find symbol` errors in `public class GfxApplet extends Applet`,
`super.init();`, and `add(app);`

Comment: `GfxApplet` should be it's own class, don't forget to include `import java.awt.*`

Comment: I have done so. Specifically, my first error appears on `Applet` as `Cannot find symbol.`

Comment: Sorry, it's `import java.applet.Applet` :P - I've added the import statements to the example code above

Comment: Yes, I am seeing some progress. The project now compiles. Now my problem is that the Applet viewer merely says "Applet started" without the `string` I expected it to say. Located in `g.drawString` in `GfxApp` class.

Comment: Trying adding `setLayout(new BorderLayout());` after the `super.init()` call (you'll need to include `java.awt.*` - see what I mean by "better support" been years since I last dealt with applets in any real capacity

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this community and it brings me joy that they're are wonderful people like you willing to help a beginner out. I'm not sure why `awt` is still in the curriculum if it's been outdated for almost 2 decades. Just so I'm not violating any policies here, will you explain to me what the `GfxNode` class is, what it does, and what it is for?

Comment: Glad it could help. The `GfxNode` seems to simply be a representation of an element which simply makes it easier to graphically represent a `LinkedList` (so each `GfxNode` is a link)